# Editing a comment for flag

Tags: discussion

I flagged a post, about which I couldn't take decision  on my own (whether to close or consider to advise to protect or to leave open). So I was seeking help from Mods.

I marked it as "OTHERS" and wrote my concerns as comment. But after submitting the flag. I realized that I made a typo and/or missed an important point to notify. Since there is no edit option available. How to communicate with mods about it? or how to resend the comment?

Comment: If your flag get declined/helpful, and the action is not taken what you wanted, flag it again.

Comment: @hims056, thank you! that was a valuable suggestion :)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Updating answer from @hims056's comment:*

Stackoverflow provides an option to flag the same post more than one time.

If the action, that you expected was not taken, then flag and write the necessary comment.